# Input types in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML has various input types like text,date,email,url,etc. which is recognized by many browsers and thus almost every browser does validation by itself.

Now lets say I have a textarea and I want every line of textarea to be of a type.

Eg. I want each line of a textarea to hold content of type email address. Is there any way to specify it without using JS?

**I know this is syntactically wrong but something like:**

```
<textarea type="email"></textarea>
```

And if it is not possible without JS, how do we implement this functionality in JS/jQuery with very little code?

Comment: one email address per line ?

Comment: This is not possible sorry

Comment: yes. not email address alone.. I just gave an eg. it can be one date per line or one number per line.. any input type basically supported by html5

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There might be a workaround.

Comment: @Nick: I am making a social networking website where user has ability to input data against various fields and it is easy for 1 element. but lets say user wants to input multiple contact numbers or multiple email address, so, I have to code separately for that in JS to append new elements to the dom and validate it again on input.. So, i wanted an easy way to do this..

Comment: If you want to support multiple values and make use of the structured html5 input types, why not just use multiple inputs? It might not be as pretty as you want out-of-the-box, but CSS can fix that.

Comment: @BobbyJack: i was using multiple inputs but things are getting messier when each input element is added to dom.. Cause I have to then join all multiple inputs together in the server side since I am storing all inputs together in a single column in db and then split it again during display since each element has to be editable

Comment: @vignesh: well, the storing of multiple values in a single db column isn't *great* ... I still think multiple inputs is the best approach. You know you can name them with trailing `[]` and they'll be submitted as an array to the server, right? Makes things much easier.

Comment: you are right.. but it was just a pain in the ass to program everything like that.. will do this way then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to restrict user to enter email address per line in HTML or JQuery. However you can partially achieve similar functionality using JQuery. You have to tell user to provide email address in each line i.e. user have to press enter after entering email address in a line of text area. Then you can write below code to achieve your funcionality.

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(){
  // validate or write your logic here
});
```

You can also ask user to type multiple email address separated by comma(,). Then  you have to simply  replace `'\n'` in above code to `','`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As your answer and the other comments state, I think there is no way to do it in just HTML.